# Table Fix Height For All Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want table content to align center for horizontal and vertical. I've done for that. But I need help to fix some code. Check out this JSFiddle and example code below: http://jsfiddle.net/yiedpozi/a8ZLJ/

CSS example code:

```
div.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}

table {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td, tr {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
}

span.description {
    display: none;
}
```

JS example code:

```
$('td').hover(
  function () {
        $(this).find('span.description').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
  }, 
  function () {
        $(this).find('span.description').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
  }
);
```

You can see, if hover, it will show description, but height of table row will increase. I want it to be fix, so, before hover, title will center, when hover, all content will center, but not affect table content height. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a `height` in `td`, to a value which can hold both default and hover content.

```
td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 120px; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8ZLJ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Update the following css classes:

```
td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    height:100px;
}

span.description {
    display: none;
    height:80px;
    overflow:auto; 
}
```

look at [the updated JSFillde](http://jsfiddle.net/adelassi/a8ZLJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a div tag inside each  with class on div.

Just like that.

```
 <td>
   <div class="setHeight">
     <span class="title">This Is Title</span>
        <span class="description">Here is description. Here is description. Here is description. Here is description. Here is description.</span>
                </div>
</td>
```

You can add setHeight class as well.

```
    div .setHeight{
    width:auto;
   height:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CodeAstro/a8ZLJ/2/